# Why can't such functions be found in specified libraries?

Tags: g++

This is my command

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image `sdl2-config  --cflags --libs` sdl2-test.cpp -o sdl2-test
```

I got result as below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4uSTR6.o: in function `main':
sdl2-test.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: sdl2-test.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/usr/bin/ld: sdl2-test.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `IMG_Init'
....
```

But I actually found list of such 'undefinded reference' in the specified directory/libraries:

```
stan@stan-ubuntu1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll libSDL2.a libSDL2_image.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3141130  五  31  2022 libSDL2.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  215674  二   1  2022 libSDL2_image.a

stan@stan-ubuntu1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ readelf -s libSDL.a | grep _Init
     9: 0000000000000000   385 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 SDL_InitSubSystem
    18: 0000000000000190    80 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 SDL_Init
    44: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND SDL_InitSubSystem
   135: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND SDL_Init
     3: 0000000000000010     5 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 DUMMY_InitOSKeymap
    23: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND DUMMY_InitOSKeymap
    38: 0000000000000300   850 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 X11_InitKeymap
    85: 0000000000001ac0     9 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 X11_InitOSKeymap
   195: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND X11_InitOSKeymap
    24: 00000000000002a0     9 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 DGA_InitOSKeymap
    25: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND X11_InitKeymap
    58: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND DGA_InitOSKeymap
....
```

So, how come those functions cannot be found in g++ command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Comment: Steeldriver, you're right. I changed the building command as below, and then it works:

g++  sdl2-test.cpp  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image `sdl2-config  --cflags --libs` -o sdl2-test

Answer (score 0):

As Steeldrver said, I revised the command, changing order of parameter in command line, it works then. The revised command is as follows:

```
g++  sdl2-test.cpp  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image `sdl2-config  --cflags --libs` -o sdl2-test
```

Just moved sdl2-test.cpp to the front, right after 'g++', and it works.